# in bash linux how to echo escaped text as output of a command

Tags: bash, text, escaping, echo

I want to print a text example

```
 '(]\{&}$"\n
```

the escaped version I have is this:

```
"'(]\\{&}$\"\\n"
```

I tried the following:

```
cat $CLIPBOARD_HISTORY_FILE | sed "$2!d" |  sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/'
cat $CLIPBOARD_HISTORY_FILE | sed "$2!d" |  sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/'  | eval 'stdin=$(cat); echo  "$stdin"'
VAR1=$(cat $CLIPBOARD_HISTORY_FILE | sed "$2!d" |  sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/')
VAR2="'(]\\{&}\$\"\\n"
VAR3=$VAR1
echo "1  '(]\\{&}\$\"\\n"
echo "2  $VAR1"
echo "3  $VAR2"
echo "4  $VAR3"
echo -e "5  $VAR1"
echo -e "6  $VAR2"
echo -e "7  $VAR3"


$ 
'(]\\{&}$\"\\n
'(]\\{&}$\"\\n
1  '(]\{&}$"\n
2  '(]\\{&}$\"\\n
3  '(]\{&}$"\n
4  '(]\\{&}$\"\\n
5  '(]\{&}$\"\n
6  '(]\{&}$"

7  '(]\{&}$\"\n
```

echoing the text directly works, but not if it comes from a command.... what am I not seeing or understanding?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's best to enclose material in single quotes rather than double quotes; then you only have to worry about single quotes.  Thus:

```
$ x="'"'(]\{&}$"\n'
$ printf "%s\n" "$x"
'(]\{&}$"\n
$ printf "%s\n" "$x" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"
''\''(]\{&}$"\n'
$
```

The use of `printf` is important; it doesn't futz with its data, unlike `echo`.
The `'\''` sequence is crucial; it stops the current single quoted string, outputs a single quote and then restarts the single quoted string.  That output is 'sub-optimal'; the initial `''` could be left out (and similarly the final `''` could be left out if the data ends with a single quote):

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$x" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/" -e "s/^''//" -e "s/''$//"
\''(]\{&}$"\n'
$
```

If you really must have double quotes around the data, rather than single quotes, then you have to escape more (`` $`\" `` need protection), but the concept is similar.

Comment: thanks. The problem is that the escaped text I have is generated by another script in ruby of which I have no idea, so I was hoping to find a way to translate the input I get. when I use printf I get error messages on some cases including \, %, or ' also, I need elements like \n to be interpreted as a new line, therefore the double quotes ... but I will try your examples more in detail soon